# Remove element if it assessed as blank

Tags: jquery

How do you remove an element if it is blank after checking its current status on button click?

In my case I have 4 input elements each in their own waypoint-container div. When the save button is pressed, I want to check if any of them are empty. The empty input elements will be removed. However, the first input element cannot be removed.

This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save-waypoint-button').click(function () {
        checkIfWaypointBlank()
    });
});

function checkIfWaypointBlank() {
    $('.waypoint-container input').each(function (index, element) {
        if (index > 0 && $('$this:text').is(":empty")) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m1m118kd/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(this).val()`:

```
function checkIfWaypointBlank() {
    $('.waypoint-container input').each(function (index, element) {
        if (index > 0 && $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m1m118kd/5/)**

Comment: @methuselah good catch on the missing class dot in `$('.waypoint-container input')`

Comment: Those things get me all the time. Code works perfectly - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Your selector is missing a `.`: `$('.waypoint-container input')`
2. You are referencing this, which in the each function context is global.

   ```
   var list = $('.waypoint-container input');
   console.log(list); //Just to ensure you are getting items...
   list.each(function (index, element) {
       if(!index) return;
       var item = $(element);
       if(item.text().trim() == '')
           item.parent().remove();
   });
   ```

   }

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1m118kd/4/

Comment: The code block is acting funky whenever I try to add `function checkIfWaypointBlank()  `